# PHP - Não consigo dar update na base de dados

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Não consigo dar update na base de dados, alguém me pode ajudar pfv?

```
<?php

$ligaBD = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pap");

$tipo_autorizacao = $_POST['tipo_autorizacao'];
$autorizacao_obs = $_POST['autorizacao_obs'];

$linhaProposta = "INSERT INTO propostas () VALUES()";
$resultado = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $linhaProposta);

// Ir buscar o nproposta da proposta
$npropostaLinha = "SELECT nproposta FROM propostas ORDER BY nproposta DESC";
$resultado = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $npropostaLinha);
$nproposta = "";
printf($npropostaLinha);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_NUM);
printf("==> ");
print_r($row[0]);
$nproposta = $row[0];

$insertAutorizacao = "INSERT INTO autorizacao (nproposta,tipo_autorizacao,autorizacao_obs) 
                    VALUES ($nproposta,'$tipo_autorizacao','$autorizacao_obs')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $insertAutorizacao);
$selectAutorizacao = "SELECT autorizacao FROM propostas WHERE nproposta='$nproposta'";

$updateAutorizacao = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $selectAutorizacao);

if ($row["autorizacao"] == "autorizacao_sim") {
    $updateAutorizacao = "UPDATE propostas SET autorizacao='Autorizado' WHERE nproposta='$nproposta'";
} else if ($row["autorizacao"] == "autorizacao_nao") {
    $updateAutorizacao = "UPDATE propostas SET autorizacao='Nao Autorizado' WHERE nproposta='$nproposta'";
}

$resultado = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $updateAutorizacao);
header('Location: ./conselhoadmin.php');
mysqli_close($ligaBD);
?>
```

erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual erro está acusando?

Comment: esqueci-me de meter, já editei. obrigado

Comment: O erro está aqui `$row["autorizacao"]` da onde saiu esse `$row`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fiz algumas modificações, funcionou aqui, levei em consideração que sua telabe tenha o modelo que coloquei no insert, qualuqer coisa e só modificar.

$ligaBD = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pap");

$tipo_autorizacao = $_POST['tipo_autorizacao'];
$autorizacao_obs = $_POST['autorizacao_obs'];

$linhaProposta = "INSERT INTO `propostas` (`nproposta`, `tipo_autorizacao`, `autorizacao_obs`, `autorizacao`) VALUES ( '1234', '1234', '1234', 'autorizacao_sim');";
$resultado = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $linhaProposta);

// Ir buscar o nproposta da proposta
$npropostaLinha = "SELECT nproposta FROM propostas ORDER BY nproposta DESC";
$resultado = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $npropostaLinha);
$nproposta = "";
printf($npropostaLinha);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_NUM);
printf("==> ");
print_r($row[0]);
$nproposta = $row[0];

$insertAutorizacao = "INSERT INTO autorizacao (nproposta,tipo_autorizacao,autorizacao_obs) 
                    VALUES ($nproposta,'$tipo_autorizacao','$autorizacao_obs')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $insertAutorizacao);
$selectAutorizacao = "SELECT autorizacao FROM propostas WHERE nproposta='$nproposta'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $selectAutorizacao)) {

/* fetch associative array */
while ($rowline = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    if ($rowline["autorizacao"] == "autorizacao_sim") {
        $updateAutorizacao = "UPDATE propostas SET autorizacao='Autorizado' WHERE nproposta='$nproposta'";
    } else if ($rowline["autorizacao"] == "autorizacao_nao") {
        $updateAutorizacao = "UPDATE propostas SET autorizacao='Nao Autorizado' WHERE nproposta='$nproposta'";
    }
    if ($rowline["autorizacao"] != "Autorizado") {
        mysqli_query($ligaBD, $updateAutorizacao);
    }
}

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);}

Comment: Desde já obrigado pela resposta.
No entanto experimentei esse codigo e deu este erro http://prntscr.com/nak4ul

Comment: tenta trocar o codigo do if por esse;

if ($rowline["autorizacao"] == "autorizacao_sim" || $rowline["autorizacao"] == "autorizacao_nao" ) {

acredito que vai dá certo, tem algum valor em autorizacao que esta deixando passar assim resolve.
   mysqli_query($ligaBD, $updateAutorizacao);
  }

Comment: if ($rowline["autorizacao"] == "autorizacao_sim" || $rowline["autorizacao"] == "autorizacao_nao" ) {
   mysqli_query($ligaBD, $updateAutorizacao);
  }

Comment: já conseguir resolver, muito obrigado

Comment: De nada! qualuqer coisa e só falr.

Answer (score 0):

Achei o possível erro, faltava definir a variável `$row`, que contem o array trago pelo `SELECT` que vai definir a operação de `UPDATE`

```
    $resultado=mysqli_query($ligaBD, $insertAutorizacao);
    $selectAutorizacao = "SELECT autorizacao FROM propostas WHERE nproposta='$nproposta'";  

    $updateAutorizacao = mysqli_query($ligaBD, $selectAutorizacao);

    //*********************************************************************
    // aqui está o que faltava

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($updateAutorizacao);

    //*********************************************************************

    if($row["autorizacao"] == "autorizacao_sim") {

        $updateAutorizacao = "UPDATE propostas SET autorizacao='Autorizado' WHERE nproposta='$nproposta'";  

    }else if ($row["autorizacao"] == "autorizacao_nao"){

        $updateAutorizacao = "UPDATE propostas SET autorizacao='Nao Autorizado' WHERE nproposta='$nproposta'";  

    }       
    $resultado=mysqli_query($ligaBD, $updateAutorizacao);
    if(!$resultado){
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($ligaBD));
    }
```

Comment: Agora aparece este erro
http://prntscr.com/nah727

Comment: ja editei, é mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: desapareceram os dois primeiros erros, agora é só o erro do parameter 2.
obrigado por me estar a ajudar

Comment: reeditei a resposta, mas acredito que seja problema com `$row["autorizacao"]` acredito que a query não esteja sendo definida

Comment: vou tentar pesquisar mais um pouco, obrigado à mesma!

Comment: Faz um teste, da um `var_dump($row)` para certificar que está vindo o que vc queria

Comment: deu isso
http://prntscr.com/nahray

Comment: `$row["autorizacao"]='Por Autorizar'`, como no `if()` que vai definir qual `UPDATE` deverá ser feito não tem essa opção, ele não esta passando a `query` para o `mysqli_query`